# Coordinar texto e imágenes en aplicación hecha con App Inventor

Tags: imagen, appinventor

Tengo varios elementos:

-imagen1

-TextBox1

-imagen2

-imagen3

Quiero que al meter unos determinados carácteres en el TextBox1, por ejemplo "21", me desaparezca la imagen1 y me aparezca la imagen2.
Si no se mete, "21" y se pone otra cosa me aparezca la imagen3
Situo estos elementos en el screen pero no sé que bloques usar para hacer lo que describo.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Espero que te pueda servir , utiliza el sensor clock para lograr esto. saluditos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]